# How else can I strip a domain name from webpage with no additional library - python?

Tags: python, regex, http, url, python-2.7

The post [Get domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626535/get-domain-name-from-url)
suggested multiple libraries to get the top level domain. but

**how else can I strip a domain name from webpage with no additional library?**

I had tried it with regex it seems to work but I am sure there are better ways of doing it and lots of urls that will break the regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143342/how-else-can-i-strip-a-domain-name-from-webpage-with-no-additional-library-pyt"
>>> domain = re.sub("(http://|http://www\\.|www\\.)","",url).split('/')[0]
>>> domain
'stackoverflow.com'
>>> url = "www.apple.com/itune"
>>> re.sub("(http://|http://www\\.|www\\.)","",url).split('/')[0]
>>> 'apple.com'
```

I've also tried urlparse but it ends up with `None`:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> url ='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143342/how-else-can-i-strip-a-domain-name-from-webpage-with-no-additional-library-pyt'
>>> urlparse(url).hostname
'stackoverflow.com'
>>> url = 'www.apple.com/itune'
>>> urlparse(url).hostname
>>>
```

Comment: [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) is not an external library. Why don't you use it?

Comment: still checking whether my urls break the `urlparse`, i would have use a regex if possible to see how much i get hasten the process... it's a long list, lol...

Comment: If `urlparse` does not handle the url, please report a bug.

Comment: why do you think that regex would hasten the parsing?

Comment: see appended question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about make a function that wraps `urlparse` ?

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>>
>>> def extract_hostname(url):
...     components = urlparse(url)
...     if not components.scheme:
...         components = urlparse('http://' + url)
...     return components.netloc
...
>>> extract_hostname('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143342')
'stackoverflow.com'
>>> extract_hostname('www.apple.com/itune')
'www.apple.com'
>>> extract_hostname('file:///usr/bin/python')
''
```

Comment: checking components' scheme sounds good =), in fact there are many more instances of `urlparse(url).hostname` becoming Noney, i guess i'll have to catch whatever i can and just throw the noney ones...

Answer (score 0):

Use [urllib.parse](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) standard library.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143342/how-else-can-i-strip-a-domain-name-from-webpage-with-no-additional-library-pyt'
>>> urlparse(url).hostname
'stackoverflow.com'
```

Comment: isn't it from `from urlparse import urlparse` ??

Comment: For python2, yes. My example is for python3