# sklearn - how to use TfidfVectorizer to use entire strings?

Tags: python, nlp, preprocessor, scikit-learn

I have this problem where I am using the hostnames of all the URLs I have in my dataset as features. I'm not able to figure out how to use TfidfVectorizer to extract hostnames only from the URLs and calculate their weights. 
For instance, I have a dataframe df where the column 'url' has all the URLs I need. I thought I had to do something like:

```
def preprocess(t):
    return urlparse(t).hostname

tfv = TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocess)

tfv.fit_transform([t for t in df['url']])
```

It doesn't seem to work this way, since it splits the hostnames instead of treating them as whole strings. I think it's to do with analyzer='word' (which it is by default), which splits the string into words.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. `analyzer=word` creates a tokeniser that uses the default token pattern `'(?u)\b\w\w+\b'`. If you wanted to tokenise the entire URL as a single token, you can change the token pattern:

```
vect = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='\S+')
```

This tokenises `https://www.pythex.org hello hello.there` as `['https://www.pythex.org', 'hello',  'hello.there']`. You can then create an analyser to extract the hostname from URLs as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626535/get-domain-name-from-url). You can either extend `CountVectorizer` to change its `build_analyzer` method or just monkey patch it:

```
def my_analyser():
    # magic is a function that extracts hostname from URL, among other things
    return lambda doc: magic(preprocess(self.decode(doc)))

vect = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='\S+')
vect. build_analyzer = my_analyser
vect.fit_transform(...)
```

Note: tokenisation is not as simple as is appears. The regex I've used has many limitations, e.g. it doesn't split the last token of a sentence and the first token of the next sentence if there isn't a space after the full stop. In general, regex tokenisers get very unwieldy very quickly. I recommend looking at `nltk`, which offers several different non-regex tokenisers.