# Extract domain name from URL in Python

Tags: python, url, server, package

I am tring to extract the domain names out of a list of URLs. Just like in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331948/extract-domain-name-from-the-url
My problem is that the URLs can be about everything, few examples:
`m.google.com` => `google`
`m.docs.google.com` => `google`
`www.someisotericdomain.innersite.mall.co.uk` => `mall`
`www.ouruniversity.department.mit.ac.us` => `mit`
`www.somestrangeurl.shops.relevantdomain.net` => `relevantdomain` 
`www.example.info` => `example`
And so on..
The diversity of the domains doesn't allow me to use a regex as shown in [how to get domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url) (because my script will be running on enormous amount of urls from real network traffic, the regex will have to be enormous in order to catch all kinds of domains as mentioned).
Unfortunately my web research the didn't provide any efficient solution.
Does anyone have an idea of how to do this ?
Any help will be appreciated ! 
Thank you

Comment: Can u use an external lib?

Comment: Gather a list of top-level domains, split your url by dots, right-strip your url from TLD, extract name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get domain name from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url)

Comment: Yes, I can use external libs.
It is not a duplication (I even attached a link to this thread), I couldn't find a satisfying answer there.

Comment: Use [**`urllib.parse`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get protocol + host name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626535/get-protocol-host-name-from-url)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `tldextract` which is more efficient version of `urlparse`,  `tldextract` accurately separates the `gTLD` or `ccTLD` (generic or country code top-level domain) from the registered `domain` and `subdomains` of a URL.

```
>>> import tldextract
>>> ext = tldextract.extract('http://forums.news.cnn.com/')
ExtractResult(subdomain='forums.news', domain='cnn', suffix='com')
>>> ext.domain
'cnn'
```

Comment: Note: the `tldextract` library makes an http request upon initial install and creates a cache of the latest tld data. This can raise a permission error for some remote deployments. See here: https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract#note-about-caching

Answer (score 5):

It seems you can use urlparse https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html for that url, and then extract the netloc.

And from the netloc you could easily extract the domain name by using split

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately, using urlparse on url like `m.city.domain.com` returned me  `ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='m.city.domain.com', params='', query='', fragment='')`, while the expected output was `domain`

Comment: Use a valid URL (//m.city.domain.com/), not a something like (m.city.domain.com). Nobody can guess what did you pass when you removed backslashes.

Comment: @kobibo `urlparse` follows [rfc 1808 syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1808.html) which requires `//` before `net_loc` https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 2):

For extracting domain from url

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021846/extract-domain-name-from-url-in-python"
domain = urlparse(url).netloc
"stackoverflow.com"
```

For check domain is exist in url

```
if urlparse(url).netloc in ["domain1", "domain2", "domain3"]:
           do something
```

Comment: `pu.netloc` may include port. You might want `pu.hostname` instead (to get the domain without port).

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution via regex

```py
import re

def domain_name(url):
    return url.split("www.")[-1].split("//")[-1].split(".")[0]
```

Comment: Gets the first part of the domain, not the actual domain. Only works for things like www.google.com

Comment: Unreliable solution, avoid.

Answer (score 0):

With regex, you could use something like this:

`(?<=\.)([^.]+)(?:\.(?:co\.uk|ac\.us|[^.]+(?:$|\n)))`

https://regex101.com/r/WQXFy6/5

Notice, you'll have to watch out for special cases such as `co.uk`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) and [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) methods.

PS: ONLY WORKS FOR SIMPLE LINKS LIKE `https://youtube.com` (output=youtube)    AND `(www.user.ru.com)` (output=user)

def domain_name(url):

```
return url.replace("www.","http://").split("//")[1].split(".")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def getDomain(url:str) -> str:
    '''
        Return the domain from any url
    '''
    # copy the original url text
    clean_url = url

    # take out protocol
    reg = re.findall(':[0-9]+',url)
    if len(reg) > 0:
        url = url.replace(reg[0],'')
    
    # take out paths routes
    if '/' in url:
        url = url.split('/')

    # select only the domain
    if 'http' in clean_url:
        url = url[2]

    # preparing for next operation
    url = ''.join(url)

    # select only domain
    url = '.'.join(url.split('.')[-2:])

    return url
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import validators

    hostnames = []
    counter = 0
    errors = 0
    for row_orig in rows:
        try:
            row = row_orig.rstrip().lstrip().split(' ')[1].rstrip()
            if len(row) < 5:
                print(f"Empty row {row_orig}")
                errors += 1
                continue
            if row.startswith('http'):
                domain = urlparse(row).netloc # works for https and http
            else:
                domain = row

            if ':' in domain:
                domain = domain.split(':')[0] # split at port after clearing http/https protocol 

            # Finally validate it
            if validators.domain(domain):
                pass
            elif validators.ipv4(domain):
                pass
            else:
                print(f"Invalid domain/IP {domain}. RAW: {row}")
                errors +=1
                continue

            hostnames.append(domain)
            if counter % 10000 == 1:
                print(f"Added {counter}. Errors {errors}")
            counter+=1
        except:
            print("Error in extraction")
            errors += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tests = {
  "m.google.com": 'google',
  "m.docs.google.com": 'google',
  "www.someisotericdomain.innersite.mall.co.uk": 'mall',
  "www.ouruniversity.department.mit.ac.us": 'mit',
  "www.somestrangeurl.shops.relevantdomain.net": 'relevantdomain',
  "www.example.info": 'example',
  "github.com": 'github',
}

def get_domain(url, loop=0, data={}):

  dot_count = url.count('.')

  if not dot_count:
    raise Exception("Invalid URL")

  # basic
  if not loop:
    if dot_count < 3:
      data = {
        'main':  url.split('.')[0 if dot_count == 1 else 1]
        }

  # advanced
  if not data and '.' in url:
      if dot_count > 1:
        loop += 1
        start = url.find('.')+1
        end = url.rfind('.') if dot_count != 2 else None
        return get_domain(url[start:end], loop, data)
      else:
        data ={
          'main': url.split('.')[-1]
          }

  return data

for u, v in tests.items():
  print(get_domain(u))
```