# Python regex pattern which search for domain name

Tags: python, regex, findall

**I got a list of links and some of them look like**

**https://www.domainname**
or **https://domainname**

I need to make a regex pattern to get only the domain name from it.
This "www" make problems in my pattern :(

```
print(re.findall("//([a-zA-Z]+)", i))
```

Comment: You can create an optional non-capturing group - `re.findall(r"//(?:www\.)?([a-zA-Z]+)", i)`

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021846/extract-domain-name-from-url-in-python can help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the end of the string.

```
url = "https://www.domainname"
url2 = "https://domainname"


for u in [url, url2]:
    print(f'{u}')
    print(re.findall(r"\w+$", url2))

https://www.domainname
['domainname']
https://domainname
['domainname']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    readfile = file.read()

    search = re.finditer('(?:\w+:\/\/)?(?:\w+\.)(\w+)(\.\w+)', readfile)

    for check in search:
        print(check.group(1)) #type 1 : if you want only domain names
```

result :

```
domainname
example
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
import re

l1 = ["https://www.domainname1", "https://domainname2"]
for i in l1:
    print(re.findall("/(?:www\.)?(\w+)", i))
```

Output:

```
['domainname1']
['domainname2']
```