# How to remove https,www and everything to get only domain?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to get the URLs in the search page using the script below

```
def get_source(url):
    """Return the source code for the provided URL. 

    Args: 
        url (string): URL of the page to scrape.

    Returns:
        response (object): HTTP response object from requests_html. 
    """

    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        response = session.get(url)
        return response

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)

   def scrape_google(query):

    query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
    response = get_source("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + query)

    links = list(response.html.absolute_links)
    google_domains = ('https://www.google.', 
                      'https://google.', 
                      'https://webcache.googleusercontent.', 
                      'http://webcache.googleusercontent.', 
                      'https://policies.google.',
                      'https://support.google.',
                      'https://maps.google.',
                      'https://play.google.')
    https = ('https://')

    for url in links[:]:
        if url.startswith(google_domains):
            links.remove(url)
        
    return links
```

And now I want to get plain domains without https, www or anything like below

```
wiki.org
itroasters.com
```

And also need to remove any duplicates.

Could anyone please help me to get the expected result?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a web-scraping question, it's a simple text parsing question.  Have you tried anything at all?  Do you realize Python has a `urllib` module that includes a `parse` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract domain name from URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021846/extract-domain-name-from-url-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I have updated the Tags.  Yes, I understand that urilib includes a parse function.  As I'm new to using Python, I couldn't find how to use that in this script.

Comment: I can understand why you might want to remove the scheme but why might you want to remove 'www'? Remember, 'www.a.b.c' is not necessarily the same as 'a.b.c'

Answer (score 0):

The use-case for removing a 'www.' preamble to a netloc/path is not explained in the question and is probably unwise.

Here's a pattern that will provide isolation of the netloc/path with or without a 'www.' preamble. This code will also handle URLs that do not have a scheme. Any other prefixes that need to be removed can be added to the PREFIXES list:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from typing import Iterator

# a list of prefixes to remove
# there's only one initially but this construct means that others
# could be added without needing to adjust the runtime code
PREFIXES = [
    'www.'
]

google_domains = [
    'https://www.google.',
    'https://google.',
    'https://webcache.googleusercontent.',
    'http://webcache.googleusercontent.',
    'https://policies.google.',
    'https://support.google.',
    'https://maps.google.',
    'https://play.google.',
]

def strip_scheme(urls: list[str], remove: bool=False) -> Iterator[str]:
    for url in urls:
        _, netloc, path, *_ = urlparse(url)
        rv = netloc or path
        if remove:
            for prefix in PREFIXES:
                if rv.startswith(prefix):
                    rv = rv[len(prefix):]
                    break
        yield rv


print(set(strip_scheme(google_domains)))
print()
print(set(strip_scheme(google_domains, True)))
```

**Output:**

```
['maps.google.', 'support.google.', 'webcache.googleusercontent.', 'google.', 'www.google.', 'policies.google.', 'play.google.']

['maps.google.', 'support.google.', 'webcache.googleusercontent.', 'google.', 'policies.google.', 'play.google.']
```