# Parsing DN, attributes from LDAP URL in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, python-ldap, ldap3

I have an URL "ldap://ldap.infonotary.com/dc=identity-ca,dc=infonotary,dc=com"

I wanted to get the LDAP DN and attributes from this URL using ldap3 library in python3.
If I pass the whole URL to a class, I should be able to get DN, attributes from its functions. Also I should get hostname, extensions, port.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get protocol + host name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626535/get-protocol-host-name-from-url) (If you just need to get the URL, such as hostname and the path. You could easily iterate over each `path.split(',')` and do a `identifier, value = item.split('=')`)

Comment: LDAP URL parsing is a bit special. So for various reasons one should use a decent module for that. And therefore the question is **not** a dup of the other question.

Comment: I agree, LDAP URL parsing is different from the HTTP URL parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `ldap3.utils.uri.parse_uri()` is your friend which returns a dictionary with the URL components:

```
>>> import ldap3.utils.uri    
>>> ldap3.utils.uri.parse_uri('ldap://ldap.infonotary.com/dc=identity-ca%2cdc=infonotary%2cdc=com')['base']
'dc=identity-ca,dc=infonotary,dc=com'
```