# How can I get ip address, if I have full url, using function socket.gethostbyname?

Tags: python, sockets

I need to get ip address of website, for example, 'https://www.facebook.com/'

This code returns ip address:

```
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname('www.facebook.com')
print('ip_address = ', ip_address) # prints 185.60.216.35
```

But this code:

```
  ip_address = socket.gethostbyname('https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=110')
```

throws an exception:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Is there any way in python to get ip address from this link 'https://www.facebook.com/' without retrieving www.facebook.com ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get protocol + host name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626535/get-protocol-host-name-from-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [urllib.parse.urlsplit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) to get the hostname from the domain, then get the IP address.

`urlsplit` returns a namedtuple, its `netloc` attribute is the hostname.

```
>>> import socket
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> url = 'https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=110'
>>> split_url = parse.urlsplit(url)
>>> ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(split_url.netloc)

>>> print(ip_address)
157.240.1.35
```