# Cross checking and validating two input fields in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am new to python and Django, i wanted to know how below thing can be possible?

```
input field 1 - Enter name - abc@yoyo.com
input field 2 - Enter Url - www.yoyo.com
 Submit button
```

**so I want to validate the email domain and the URL name is same**. Suppose if abc@**yoyo.com** is not similar to the URL field (www.**yo.com**) so show an error. else if it's same then proceed.

How can this be implemented in Django?

Comment: If you need to do validation that depends on more than one field, use the form's `clean()` method.  See the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Comment: @JohnGordon  i am new to this, so a pseudo code would be better for my understanding.

Comment: Go to the page I linked.  It's better than any example I could make up.

Answer (score 0):

**You could do this in either the front end or backend**

**Frontend implementation with Javascript.**

```
<input id="email" type="text"> <br>
<input id="domain_id" type="text" onblur="checkDomain()">

<button type="button">Submit</button>

<script>
function checkDomain() {
  var domain = document.getElementById("email").value.split("@")[1];
  var domain2 = document.getElementById("domain_id").value;

  if (domain != domain2){
  alert("Domains don't match"); 
  }

}
</script>
```

**Backend implementation in Django (assumes use of Django Forms)**

You would put this in your forms.py within your form.

```
    def clean_domain(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        domain= self.cleaned_data.get('domain')
        email_domain = #some method to get the domain of the email
        if email_domain != domain:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'The domain must match the domain in your email')
        return domain
```

Comment: Your code worked fine for me, I just have another question. what if there is a query like this www.xyz.com/.php?id=1 and i want to get only xyz.com out of this and match with the email (info@xyz.com). what can be done in this case?

Comment: Something like this would do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626535/get-protocol-host-name-from-url

Comment: i wanted this in javascript.

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-hostname-name-from-string/54947757

Comment: didn't find any solution there please help me match xyz.com from www.xyz.com/.php?id = with email xyz.com

Comment: there is a drawback to your above javascript. even after showing alert when ok is clicked the form proceeds further.

Comment: If you want to prevent the user from going further, add something like this:

document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;  on setup and put it in an else block after the alert.

Comment: this didn't work, it still went further after clicking the ok button on alert.

Comment: See my latest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new answer based on your latest comments:

```
<input id="email" type="text"> <br>
<input id="domain_id" type="text" onblur="checkDomain()">

<button id="myBtn" type="button">Submit</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
function checkDomain() {
  var domain = document.getElementById("email").value.split("@")[1];
  var domain2 = document.getElementById("domain_id").value;

  if (domain != domain2){
  alert("Domains don't match"); 
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
  }

}
</script>
```