# Stack Exchange SEO technique

Tags: seo, stackexchange

Stack Exchange uses the following URL format for questions:

```
+-----------------------------------+-------+----------------------------+
|                                   |   ID  |                            |
+-----------------------------------+-------+----------------------------+
| http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234567/question-heading            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http://stackoverflow.com/users    /1234567/user-name                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Though the question loads without the question heading, ie. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234567`, then why does Stack Exchange use the `question-heading` and `user-name` part of the URL?

WordPress too uses a similar URL redressing.

Is this an SEO trick or some other thing?

Comment: This belongs on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: `Is this an SEO trick` that's a large chunk of the reason, yes.

Comment: It makes URL working (with the ID) and readable (with name). That's the reason why a LOT of sites do the same thing.

Comment: @KendallFrey could you let me know who this kind of database works i mean we are getting the unique id of question table and question tag how it works ?

Comment: Oh, and for interest's sake, check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937812/this-is-pretty-cool

Comment: @KendallFrey, I don't understand what you want to tell me by giving me a link that redirects to my question itself...

Comment: @TabrezAhmed: Look at the URL. I inserted an arbitrary title, and that doesn't change where the link goes.

Comment: @KendallFrey, But the server corrects the link based on the `ID` of the question and `301`-redirects to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937812/stack-exchange-seo-technique

Comment: @KendallFrey, I still don't understand what you meant to say...

Comment: @TabrezAhmed: I said it was for interest's sake.

Comment: @KendallFrey, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12305/discussion-between-tabrez-ahmed-and-kendall-frey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having keywords in your URL is a positive ranking factor for search engines. So putting the title, username, etc, is a great way to help a page rank well for the keywords on that page since, theoretically, a well written title and question will result in answers that will also contain important, and related, keywords in them.